# What is the meaning of OMP, GWP, OGP?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, tournament

I am using [mtgarena](http://mtgarena.appspot.com/) for my tournament organization.

What do OMP, GWP and OGP mean? Does anyone know what they stand for?

Example:

```
Player  Points  OMP     GWP      OGP
1           9   33.33   100      31.11
2           6   66.67   60       69.44
3           6   44.44   75       42.22
4           6   22.22   66.67    22.22
5           3   72.22   20       80.56
6           3   50      20       53.33
7           3   33.33   0        36.11
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are percentages, used by the DCI as [tie-breakers](http://www.wizards.com/dci/downloads/tiebreakers.pdf). From Section C4 of the [Tournament Organizer's Handbook](http://www.wizards.com/dci/downloads/TOHndBk_Feb_5_07.pdf):

- OMP - **Opponents’ Match-Win Percentage.** *A player’s match-win percentage is that player’s accumulated match points divided by X
  times the number of rounds in which he or she competed, or 0.33, whichever is greater.*
- GWP - **Game-Win Percentage.** *Similar to the match-win percentage, a player’s game-win percentage is the total number of
  game points he or she earned divided by X times the number of games played.*
- OGP - **Opponents’ Game-Win Percentage.** *Similar to opponents’ match-win percentage, a player’s opponents’ game-win percentage is
  simply the average game-win percentage of all of that player’s opponents. And, as with opponents’ match-win percentage, each opponent has a minimum game-win percentage of
  0.33.*

Comment: The links in this answer are broken. What is the definition of X please?